# Using Promises and Zones in Angular2

Tags: angular

I'd like to display the result of processing a promise in a component's template. I've tried using zone.run, but that hasn't helped. Here's my component:

```
@Component({ selector: 'test' })
@View({ template:
`<div class="test">
  <p>Result: {{ result }}</p>
</div>`
})

export class Test {
  promise: Promise<string>;
  result: string;

  constructor(private _zone: NgZone) {

    // Process promise
    this._zone.run( function() {
      this.promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { resolve("Hi there"); });
      this.promise.then(function(msg: string) { this.result = msg; });
    });
  }
}
```

When this runs, the template doesn't change. I tried putting zone.run inside the then method, but that gave an error. Any thoughts?

Comment: Wild guess : You're importing `Promise` from `es6-promise`, that won't work. If my guess is correct, just remove the import. `zone-microtask` already exposes `Promise` and patchs it. If that works you can remove `zone.run`.

Comment: Thank you. I removed the import of `es6-promise` and took away `zone.run`. But the `then` method still won't update the template. I've looked for the `zone-microtask` module but I can't find it. How can I access it?

Comment: Take a look at this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/kyQcNi?p=preview). If still doesn't work for you, provide a plnkr with your example so we can see it better. You just use `Promise` because `zone` already loads it.

Comment: Aha. The problem was that I wasn't using the fat arrow function in the `then` method. `this` wasn't referencing the enclosing object, so the property wasn't being updated. Thanks, Eric!

Comment: user934904, could you please answer this question, so that others can learn from your findings... Personally it is difficult for me to follow your findings here in the comments. Please provide a real answer below :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There were two problems. First, I was importing `Promise` from es6-promise, which is different than the already-available `Promise` class. Thanks to Eric Martinez for figuring this out.

The second problem is this line of code:

```
this.promise.then(function(msg: string) { this.result = msg; });
```

The problem here is that, inside `function(...) {...}`, `this` doesn't refer to the enclosing `Test` object. To fix this, the function needs to be declared using fat-arrow notation:

```
this.promise.then((msg: string) => { this.result = msg; });
```

Just another fascinating piece of JavaScript trivia.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use a declared function:

```
...
this.promise.then(msg => this.doSomethig(msg));
}

doSomething(msg){
  this.msg = msg;
  //other stuff
}
```

Comment: It will help someone if you add explanation to it.